# No puedo ejecutar una app de Angular V11

Tags: angular

Tengo instalado Angular `15.2.1` a nivel global pero cree una app con Angular `11.2.19` cuando lo ejecuto con el comando `ng serve` me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
⠙ Generating browser application bundles (phase: 

building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.loader (D:\Angular\mi-web-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:183:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.14.1
```

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Comprueba qué versión de node admite esa versión de Angular, Angular 11 funciona con Node 10, pero Node 18 seguramente cause problemas. Te recomiendo usar nvm para gestionar las versiones de Node

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo [este hilo de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69692842/236345), el lío está en que se han actualizado protocolos y definiciones de seguridad en Angular, Node y demás. Entonces, esa app no va a funcionar sin más. Tienes varias opciones:

- Puedes migrarla a Angular 15; puedes ayudarte usando esta [guía oficial](https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-15.0) que resalta los pasos a considerar.
- Puedes seguir el consejo en el comentario de PabloLozano y montar varios entornos con `nvm`, usando uno con Angular 11 para tu app.
- Puedes usar `--openssl-legacy-provider` en el script de `start` dentro del package.json. Al instalar creo que tendrás que usar `-force`. Pero esto está expuesto a vulnerabilidades serias de seguridad y no debería ser el camino para algo que vayas a usar.